# Verilog : syntax error : unexpected SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER on using $display

Tags: verilog

My aim is to write a test fixture that reads hex values from an input file and displays it to the screen. I am using the below code but i am getting a syntax error at line " $display ("%d:%h",j,srcPacketIn[j]);". The exact error is :

** Error: C:\altera\13.0\test.v(32): near "$display": syntax error, unexpected SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER

Could anybody please help me out?

```
module test_fixtures;
parameter TestCycles = 12;
parameter ClockPeriod = 10;


reg [7:0] srcPacketIn [0:(5*TestCycles)-1];

reg clock, reset;
genvar j;


initial
    begin
        $readmemh("input.h",srcPacketIn);
    end
initial
    begin
        reset = 0;
        clock = 1;
    end

always #ClockPeriod clock = ~clock;



        for (j=0; j < 59; j=j+1)
          begin
          $display ("%d:%h",j,srcPacketIn[j]);
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: Strangely,when i use always #<time> before $display it gets compiled

Comment: For loops need to be inside a procedural block (always/initial/etc). Did you just not copy that part?

Answer (score 1):

The code works in Icarus Verilog 0.9.6 with the changes below. 
Compile/sim results here: [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/36)

```
module test_fixtures;
parameter TestCycles = 12;
parameter ClockPeriod = 10;


reg [7:0] srcPacketIn [0:(5*TestCycles)-1];

reg clock, reset;
integer j; // <-- CHANGED


initial
    begin
        $readmemh("input.h",srcPacketIn);
    end
initial
    begin
        reset = 0;
        clock = 1;
    end

always #ClockPeriod clock = ~clock;

initial begin // <-- ADDED
        for (j=0; j < 59; j=j+1)
          begin
          $display ("%d:%h",j,srcPacketIn[j]);
        end
      end // <-- ADDED
endmodule
```